# Can get umlaut in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8

I open

```
http://localhost:8080/test.jsp?document=ý
```

and this jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String d = request.getParameter("document");
```

and it gives me d=Ã½ in debugger. How can I get correct letter ý?

Comment: no crassh, but the letter was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Tomcat, you still need to tell your servlet container to use UTF8 for URIs. Edit the connector in your server.xml in Tomcats Config Directory.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

The last line is important.

I recommend reading the Character Encoding Section from Tomcats Website:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8